# X509Certificate2.Export equivalent in java

Tags: java, x509certificate

I'm trying to port some existing code from C# to Java, this specific part uses the [X509Certificate2.Export](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24ww6yzk(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get the certificate exported as `byte[]` for later encoding as Base64.

```
var pfxPassword = "passw0rd";
var appCert = new X509Certificate2("c:\\mycert.pfx", pfxPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
byte[] certificateBytes = certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, pfxPassword);
string certString = Convert.ToBase64String(certificateBytes);
System.Console.WriteLine(certString);
```

So i tried by using the [KeyStore.store()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#store(java.io.OutputStream,%20char[])) java method

```
String caPassword = "passw0rd";
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(new File("c:\\mycert.pfx")), caPassword.toCharArray());
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
keyStore.store(outputStream, caPassword.toCharArray());
byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(outputStream.toByteArray());
String result = new String(encodedBytes, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(result);
```

Accordingly with the documentation for Export and store:

> Export: Exports the current X509Certificate object to a byte array in a format described by one of the X509ContentType values, and using the specified password.

And

> store: Stores this keystore to the given output stream, and protects its integrity with the given password.

But these code snippets are giving me different results in size and content by using the same input file and passphrase, so why is this happen?

How can I obtain the same results between these languages/frameworks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I tested both code snippets (C# and Java), they both work and both PFX/PKCS12 files are valid, but the content could be different (CA-chain, keys, bag attributes, provider, …).
2. To see the content, you can analyze both files with:
    `openssl pkcs12 -info -in P12FILE.p12`
   In the output you can see what's different.
3. [KeyStore.Store](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#store(java.io.OutputStream,%20char[]))(…) stores the container/bag with EVERYTHING its instance holds (cert, CA-chain, privKey).
   [X509Certificate2.Export](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.export(v=vs.110).aspx)(...) with [X509ContentType.pfx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509contenttype(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a PFX-formatted certificate (just one certificate). And:

   > The Pkcs12 value is identical to the Pfx value.

If all you need is the X509 certificate, then this is enough:

```
String caPassword = "passw0rd";
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
ks.load(new FileInputStream( new File(“PKCS12Path") ), caPassword.toCharArray());
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)ks.getCertificate(sAlias);
String yourB64Certificate = encoder.encodeBuffer(cert.getEncoded());
```

If you need the whole container with possibly keys, and CA-chain:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ks.store(outputStream, caPassword.toCharArray());
String result = new BASE64Encoder().encode(outputStream.toByteArray());
```

If you only need one certificate, but stored/wrapped in a PKCS12 container(like in C#):

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
ks.load(null,null); //empty container
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ks.setCertificateEntry("alias", x509Cert);
String result = new BASE64Encoder().encode(outputStream.toByteArray()); //for your base64 string
```

Without more details on what you're trying to do, what you have as input, what is the expected output, what are the constraints... It's hard to give a better and less speculative answer.

Comment: Thanks! but does not work as expected, This code also gives me different results that X509Certificate2.Export

Comment: Awesome answer! FYI, I need to port the existing code, i.e the code snippet on the top of the Question, also keep calm, I'm going to check on this issue on Wed (maybe Thu - due my backlog), an let you know. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @SebB, thanks for your support. Your answer has been very useful.

Comment: @rnd, glad i could help.